# Applying settings from a GPO to a mac

Tags: macos, active-directory, group-policy

Ive got a few macs onto my domain and now im having a couple of issues with the GPOs, mainly none of them apply.

I didnt expect most of them to apply, certianly my MSI instalers and lockdowns but i was hoping that the documents re-direct would work.

Is it possible to write a script or is there a program that can pick up the documents redirect from a GPO and re-direct the macs home folder to there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an OS X server you could use MCX settings in OpenDirectory to achieve results similar to GPOs.  As it stands, the best solution I could come up with is use of a commercial Mac-GPO solution like [this](http://www.quest.com/authentication-services/Managed_Client_Extensions_for_Group_Policy_for_Mac.aspx) or [this](http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/grouppolicy.asp).

That said, if you're open to non-Group Policy methods for managing this, you could [change the location of user home directories](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071025220746340), or even try mounting the directory (I assume it's on a network share) and then using a symbolic link to point Documents there.

Comment: Gonna write a script to sym link the home folder thanks