# Active Directory and Mac OS 10.5 - how can I get the GPO's network drive on the Mac, and get the home directory of the user to map correctly?

Tags: macos, active-directory, group-policy, network-drive

I have a PowerMac G5 computer that I have joined to the Windows domain network successfully. I am able to login successfully with domain credentials. However, it does not include any of the network drives added through Group Policy. It does however include under the shared section the server that contains home folders with the entire users' directory accessible to the logged in user.

How would I be able to get the GPO's network drive on the mac? Also, how do I get the home directory of the user to map correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying settings from a GPO to a mac](http://superuser.com/questions/81804/applying-settings-from-a-gpo-to-a-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac doesn't understand "Group Policy" so any settings you create here are ignored by OS X - this goes for mapped drives using Windows scripts and Group Policy Preferences also.

OS X, however, CAN integrate with AD (as you've already done) for a user's "home" folder. The following Apple Training guide excerpt shows what can be mapped:

> **Use UNC path from Active Directory to derive network home location**
>
> When enabled, if the user account record has a home folder  specified,
>   the Mac mounts the location and creates a link in the  Dock. The
>   default protocol is smb, and can be set to afp if desired.

http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory_mav.pdf

Comment: Could you manually map the shared network drives that do not work due to no GPO support?

Comment: Just so long as the user has permission and you know the UNC then, yes, you could write an Apple script to mount the share (as above) using smb or afp... E.g. `mount volume "smb://server/share"`

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler than that: mount the shares once manually, then add them to the user's Login Items (in System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> current user in the sidebar -> Login Items tab).

Comment: That is one method and works well, but the OP has asked about GPO stuff which is automating things...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, aside from AD authentication no further rules, settings, GPO's etc can be applied to MAC devices. It's just simply not supported, MAC and Windows are *(as you know)* quite different. For obvious reasons Microsoft have not targeted AD and it's components for the MAC operating system.

They way forward is to (in my experience) turn to 3rd party software to provide that MAC 'branch' of the Windows server AD.

However, I have yet to find a decent free/open source solution so I would recommend you look at [Centrify](http://www.centrify.com/mac/group-policy-for-mac-os-x-desktops.asp). In my opinion it's the best at what it does.